# Working locally with remote DB not working with multisite

Tags: multisite, wp-config, localhost

My usual set up in my wp-config for working locally with my remote DB is as follows:

```
define('WP_HOME','http://mysite.local');
define('WP_SITEURL','ttp://mysite.local');
define('LIVE_SITEURL', 'actualsiteurl.com');

define('DB_HOST', 'IPOFREMOTEHOST);
```

This has been working on all of my local dev sites, but on this particular dev site, mysite.local is taking me to my live site url.

Any ideas on what might need to be adjusted?

Thanks!

Comment: Is the typo in `WP_SITEURL` only in the snippet here or also in your code? Do you have plugins enabled that manage redirects?

Comment: That typo was only here

Comment: Also, I disabled the redirection plugin. Still not working.